# Less invasive way of achieving right-aligned footnote markers in the left margin?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

Is there some less invasive way of achieving footnote markers that are right-aligned in the left margin (set `\marginparsep` left of the text body) than what I have used here? It seems to work the way I want, but I am pretty much just guessing...

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[text={140mm, 40mm}]{geometry}
\usepackage[marginal]{footmisc}
\makeatletter
% Copied from footmisc.sty and edited
\ifFN@para
\else
  \long\def\@makefntext#1{%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \bgroup
      \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{%
        \ifdim\footnotemargin>0pt
          \hb@xt@\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}%
        \else
          \@makefnmark
        \fi
      }%
      \leftmargin\wd\@tempboxa
      \rightmargin\z@
      \linewidth \columnwidth
      \advance \linewidth -\leftmargin
      \parshape \@ne \leftmargin \linewidth
      \footnotesize
      \@setpar{{\@@par}}%
      \leavevmode
      \llap{\box\@tempboxa}%
      \parskip\hangfootparskip\relax
      \parindent\hangfootparindent\relax
    \else
      \parindent1em
      \noindent
      \ifdim\footnotemargin>\z@
        \hb@xt@ \footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark}%
      \else
        \ifdim\footnotemargin=\z@
          \llap{\@makefnmark}%
        \else
          \llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\hss\@makefnmark\hspace{\marginparsep}}}%\llap{\hb@xt@ -\footnotemargin{\@makefnmark\hss}}%
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
    \footnotelayout#1%
    \ifFN@hangfoot
      \par\egroup
    \fi
  }
\fi
\makeatother
\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{9}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The problem with packages like footmisc is that they have to support all sorts of options that make the code more complicated. The default is `\def\@makefntext{\indent\@makefnmark}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\llap` overlaps to the left (margin). `\noindent` starts a new line (which `\llap` needs).  `\hspace` adds a gap after `\@makefnmark`.  I arbitrarily chose `\columnsep`.  `\marginparsep` would match a normal `\marginpar`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[text={140mm, 40mm}]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\def\@makefntext{\noindent\llap{\@makefnmark\hspace{\columnsep}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
  \addtocounter{footnote}{9}
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.}
\end{document}
```